# MySQL json_encode can't read query if there's no WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, datatable

I'm having problems when encoding the result of below query to a datatable.

```
SELECT e.*, d.dept_name, CONCAT(e.first_name,' ',SUBSTRING(e.middle_name, 1, 1),'. ', e.last_name,' ',e.name_suffix) AS 'name'
FROM `employees` e
JOIN department d on e.dept_id = d.dept_id
```

The above query works when run on MySQL itself but it outputs `Invalid JSON Response` inside a datatable. However, when I run the above code with a `WHERE` clause, it outputs with no problem.

```
SELECT e.*, d.dept_name, CONCAT(e.first_name,' ',SUBSTRING(e.middle_name, 1, 1),'. ', e.last_name,' ',e.name_suffix) AS 'name'
FROM `employees` e
LEFT JOIN department d on e.dept_id = d.dept_id
WHERE employee_id = '181'
```

[image]

I am using MySQLi. What could be the problem here?

EDIT: Here's my table `employees` and `department` schema.

[image]
[image]

EDIT: Here's my `retrieve.php` script.

```
<?php 

require_once 'db_connect.php';

$output = array('data' => array());

$sql = "SELECT e.*, d.dept_name, CONCAT(e.first_name,' ',SUBSTRING(e.middle_name, 1, 1),'. ', e.last_name,' ',e.name_suffix) AS 'name'
FROM `employees` e
LEFT JOIN department d on e.dept_id = d.dept_id
WHERE employee_id = '181'";
$query = $connect->query($sql);

$x = 1;
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

    $actionButton = '
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Action <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editEmployeeModal" onclick="editEmployee('.$row['employee_id'].')"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a></li>
        <li><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeEmployeeModal" onclick="removeEmployee('.$row['employee_id'].')"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove</a></li>      
      </ul>
    </div>
        ';
//$mid = substr($row['middle_name'],0,1);
//$name = $row['first_name'].' '.$mid.'. '.$row['last_name'];
    $output['data'][] = array(
        $row['employee_id'],
        $row['name'],
        $row['dept_name'],
        $row['position'],
        $row['position_level'],
        $row['employment_status'],
        $actionButton
    );

    //$x++;
}

// database connection close
$connect->close();

echo json_encode($output);
```

EDIT: Investigating further, there's no data response available for the request according to Firefox debugger, which is weird because my table isn't empty and the query is running correctly on PHPMYADMIN.

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209424/discussion-between-toh19-and-xjshiya).

Comment: Since this was tagged by admins as duplicate, I cannot answer my own question that I've solved already. I digged through Google and found this: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30246/how-to-debug-invalid-json-when-no-response-at-all-no-error-no-nothing-is-returned. I tried encoding my strings to `utf8_encode()` function and voila, it now works. Thanks @TOH19 for helping.

Comment: I changed the dupe target and utf8_encode() is not the correct answer.